# quantmod , download bond index different than the prices in yahoo finance R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to download different stock market indices and bond indices. I download the S&P 500® Bond Index price but the results are different than the website.

```
tickers  <- c("^GSPC" ,"^IXIC",'^DJI','SPXB') # S&P 500 (^GSPC) , DJI=dow jones, IXIC = nasdac,SPXB= s &p 500 bond   
data<-NULL
for (ticker in tickers) 
  data <- cbind(data,getSymbols(ticker, from = "2019-01-01", to="2019-11-30", auto.assign = F)[,4]) # we subset close price column 
colnames(data)<-tickers  # just change closing price name to tickers  name
```

Any idea why the prices of s &p 500 bond at the website is different than what I have in my code ?

Comment: I get the same numbers as on the Yahoo site. You need to show more details of which prices are different between the R results and the Yahoo site.

Comment: How different are the prices? The site only shows 2 decimal places, but the data returned from the API has more than 2.